# Voltage multiplier circuit not working

Tags: voltage, capacitor, diodes, multiplier

I am trying to make a voltage multiplier circuit.  When I connect it to mains \$120 \; V\$, the output voltage becomes \$90 \;V \;DC\$,  I do not know why this is.

- Capacitors: \$20 kV \; 1000 \; pF\$
- Diodes: \$4 \; 12\;kV \;5\;mA\$ and \$2\; 12\;kV\; 350\;mA\$

[image: 1]

*Edit* forgot to mention the \$90 \;V\$ is DC, so it is being rectified and not multiplied.

Comment: These are really small capabilities, they can't store much charge. How much current does your measurement device draw?

Comment: Go [here](http://www.diyphysics.com/category/instrumentation/high-voltage-power-supply/) and more particularly [here](http://www.diyphysics.com/2012/02/09/d-i-y-250-kv-high-voltage-dc-power-supply-with-neat-trick-for-switching-polarity/) and read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of a voltage multiplier is DC.  That is correct and to be expected.

As Dan Boschen explained, the problem is the capacitors.  They are too small.

The impedance of a 1nF capacitor at 60 Hz is over 2 megaohms.

What isn't obvious is that the total impedance goes up as the cube of the number of stages.  I did some experimenting and research on the internet a while back, and found this equation for the total impedance of a voltage multiplier:

$$ Z = \frac {4n^3 + 3n^2 - n}{2 \pi fC}$$

That's impedance in ohms given the frequency of the input and the capacitance.

You have 3 stages, so the total impedance comes to something like 280 megaohms.

---

You'll need to use much larger capacitors. Use something like 1 microfarad capacitors.  That'll get you enough current to at least be able to measure the voltage with a multimeter.

Be **careful** when using a multiplier with line voltage.

The output is low current but high voltage.  It can do nasty things to you.

The circuit itself is at line voltage.  Touching any part of it can expose you to the full line voltage and current.

Either the output or the line voltage can kill you.

Do **not** short circuit the output.  In normal operation, the output is low current DC.  When you short it, all that's between the diodes and the power supply is the first pair of capacitors.  That can supply enough current to destroy the diodes and then the capacitors.

Answer (score 0):

The capacitor values are much too low for the AC frequency given by a standard 120 VAC source (either 50 Hz or 60 Hz). Consider the series impedance for each would be in the MegOhms.  The circuit works by charging the capacitors from the rectified AC source in parallel and discharging them as a DC source (with ripple) in series. Capacitance adds in parallel to a net larger value but reduces in series (as the inverse of the sum of inverses) so the net capacitance to the load is even smaller.

You would either need to significantly increase the capacitor values or the AC frequency. Typically, the frequency would be increased as the more economical/feasible solution. Connecting to a mains is NOT recommended especially if the goal is to create a large electrostatic field where power can be minimized.

The circuit as shown in the links using a source that produces a high AC voltage (from a 5 to 12V DC source) that is likely in the 10 KHz range or higher.

This paper provides more details on the formula for predicted ripple based on the input frequency and load current: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jece/2017/4805268/